# Unable to create Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

There are two tables:

- Table `Course` with columns `CourseID (PK, int, not null)` and `DepartmentID (PK, FK, int, not null)`, and
- Table `Class` with columns `ClassID (PK, int, not null)` and `CourseID (int, not null)`.

I try to make `Class.CourseID` FK to `Course.CourseID` but I get this message:

> The columns in table 'Course' do not match an existing primary key or
>   UNIQUE constraint.

What would I do?

Comment: If you have a compound primary key made up from two columns `(CourseID, DepartmentID)` on your `Course` table - any FK referencing that table **must also** contain both columns in their FK

Comment: Why do you need a composite primary key in Course? Is Course.CourseID not unique?

Answer (score 1):

DepartmentID should not be part of the primary key of table Course.
Or if you need it like that, then restrucutre the FK in the Class table so it will reference both (so the real primary key of table Course).

Answer (score 0):

The "structure" of FK must be the same as PK - two fields. With only CourseID as a FK you can't distinguish between records.

Example:
Let c1, c2 be Course records, d1 a class record:

```
c1: {1, 1}
c2: {1, 2}
```

Now assume d1 record to be sth like {1, 1} -> you meant c1 or c2?

You should make ONLY CourseID PK or make a complex FK (CourseID, DepartmentID) or create a surrogate PK in Course table. Personally, I would go for 1st or 3rd solution